# return false; onclick submit button not working

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit

Ive been trying to get my submit button to return false if there are any error in my code, but it keeps bringing me to a broken page, i have tried in the console of firefox and there are no errors. Thanks
*the return false is at the bottom*
Code:

```
function searchForm(){
//checks all the boxes to see if there are any errors
confirmFName();

confirmLName();

confirmEmail();

confirmAddress1();

confirmAddress2();

confirmCity();

confirmCode();

confirmUName();

confirmPass();

//check to make sure a region is selected
if(nhlForm.regBox == "Choose a Country first", "Choose your Country First"){
    //shows error message
    showMessage(nhlForm.regBox, "error", "*Choose a region");
    showMessage(nhlForm.counBox, "error", "*Choose a country");
}

//checks if checkbox is checked, if not messgae will appear and form will not send
if(nhlForm.agebox.checked == true){
    showMessage(nhlForm.agebox, "bingo", "");
}else{

    //shows error message
    showMessage(nhlForm.agebox, "error", "You must be at least 14 to have an account"); 
}

if(nhlForm.checkbox.checked == true){

    showMessage(nhlForm.checkbox, "bingo", "");
}else{

    //shows error message
    showMessage(nhlForm.checkbox, "error", "You must accept the terms of use to continue"); 
}

//if there are no errors, form will send
if(document.querySelectorAll(".error").length > 0){

//dont submit the form till errors are fixed
return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to show us how that function is called

Comment: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/) please

Comment: Show where this function is called.. or please show us a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
function searchForm(){
//checks all the boxes to see if there are any errors
confirmFName();

confirmLName();

confirmEmail();

confirmAddress1();

confirmAddress2();

confirmCity();

confirmCode();

confirmUName();

confirmPass();
var flag=true;

//check to make sure a region is selected
if(nhlForm.regBox == "Choose a Country first", "Choose your Country First"){
    //shows error message
    showMessage(nhlForm.regBox, "error", "*Choose a region");
    showMessage(nhlForm.counBox, "error", "*Choose a country");
flag=false;
}

//checks if checkbox is checked, if not messgae will appear and form will not send
if(nhlForm.agebox.checked == true){
    showMessage(nhlForm.agebox, "bingo", "");
}else{

    //shows error message
    showMessage(nhlForm.agebox, "error", "You must be at least 14 to have an account"); 
flag=false;
}

if(nhlForm.checkbox.checked == true){

    showMessage(nhlForm.checkbox, "bingo", "");
}else{

    //shows error message
    showMessage(nhlForm.checkbox, "error", "You must accept the terms of use to continue"); 
flag=false;
}
 return flag;
}
```

and onSubmit="return searchForm()" in form tag